# Is there a way to contain CSS within the Div? CSS from One Div is showing up on Another Div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I am trying to understand how I to contain a CSS from one div from not starting over another div.

By that I mean, how can I place `position: fixed` on an item only inside a particular div?

For example here is my HTML and CSS and JS:

```
<div class="blueBackground"></div>

<div class="divTwo">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-10">   
        <div id="blue_square" style="top: 310px;"></div>
    </div>   
</div>

#blue_square{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 370px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px transparent;
}


$("#blue_square").css("top", $(window).height() / 2 - 90)
```

As you can see I have here to separate divs: `blueBackground` and `divTwo`.

The problem I am seeing is that my CSS from `divTwo` is somehow starting on from `blueBackground` div. Here is a snap shot: [example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSJmK.png).

I want the CSS for `#blue_square` to only apply within the `divTwo` not outside of it. Why is  the "blue sqaure" diagram starting on  `blueBackground` and not from within `divTwo`? I am trying to make it to look like this: [example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afi6j.png)

Is there something I am missing in my css or Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

short answer is:
you need to use `position: relative` prop on your .divTwo, because:

> all the position absolute elements will be placed "relative" to the
> closest position : relative parent it has.

If there isn't any parent with the `position:relative` prop, it will just be placed based on the body tag (as you are seeing in your case)

Comment: Position: relative did not work in this case.

Comment: What did you do with position:relative? Did you really put this on .divTwo? 
Show me your code when you tried to use position relative, this should solve your problem

Comment: Yes I added  on .divTwo{position: relative;} but the blue diagram position did not change. I can still see on `blueBackground` div.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that the `position: fixed` element (`#blue_square`) remains within the boundaries of its containing div (`divTwo`), you can achieve this by setting the `position` property of the containing div to `relative`. This positions the `#blue_square` element relative to its parent container. Here's how you can modify your code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="blueBackground"></div>
<div class="divTwo">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-10">   
        <div id="blue_square"></div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#blue_square {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 370px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px transparent;
}

.divTwo {
    position: relative;
}
```

By setting the `divTwo` container's position to `relative`, you ensure that the `#blue_square` element is positioned relative to the `divTwo` container. This means it will not overlap or interfere with other elements outside of `divTwo`, such as the `blueBackground` div.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I can't preview you example screenshots but if you need a "fixed" element to stay inside another div and not overflow out of it, I would suggest to use `position:sticky` instead. No JS/jQuery required.

Your HTML:

```
<div class="blueBackground"></div>

<div class="divTwo">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-10">   
        <div id="blue_square"></div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.divTwo{
 position: relative;
}

#blue_square{
 position: sticky;
 z-index: 9;
 width: 370px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 6px transparent;
 top: calc((100vw/2) - 90); /* following your jQuery logic */
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wLjunzx9/